# How to set AND condition is for all to other OR Condition in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, where-clause

I want to set the condition using `AND` and `OR` in `WHERE` clause. But the problem is AND condition is not setting to all other `OR` Condition

ex:

```
SELECT
    Item,
    Name,
    Brand,
    Date,
    StoreID
FROM
    Item
WHERE
    Date between '01-01-2017' and '30-01-2017' 
    OR Brand = 'Nike' or Brand = 'Jhonson' OR Brand = 'Polo'
```

> In my scenario I cannot use IN to select multiple Brand. So I want to set all Date filter to all the brands. How can I achieve it.

Thanks

Comment: Supposing that there is a data that is Brand=Jhonson but it is dated on feb 2005, is it supposed to appear still?

Comment: Just change the OR to AND

Comment: You shouldn't use `OR` what you need is an `AND` !

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui yes, you are correct.But I will tell you another scenario

Comment: You should never mix `AND`s and `OR`s without parentheses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have two Scenario here as follows

```
  SELECT
        Item,
        Name,
        Brand,
        Date,
        StoreID
    FROM
        Item
    WHERE
        Date between '01-01-2017' and '30-01-2017' 
        OR (Brand = 'Nike' or Brand = 'Jhonson' OR Brand = 'Polo')


SELECT
    Item,
    Name,
    Brand,
    Date,
    StoreID
FROM
    Item
WHERE
    Date between '01-01-2017' and '30-01-2017' 
    AND (Brand = 'Nike' or Brand = 'Jhonson' OR Brand = 'Polo')
```

Answer (score 1):

This would give you the all the results that match both clauses

```
WHERE
    (Date between '01-01-2017' and '30-01-2017') 
     AND 
    (Brand IN ('Nike','Jhonson','Polo'))
```

This would give you everything that matches any of the clauses

```
WHERE
    (Date between '01-01-2017' and '30-01-2017') 
     OR 
    (Brand IN ('Nike','Jhonson','Polo'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    Item,
    Name,
    Brand,
    Date,
    StoreID
FROM
    Item
WHERE
    Date between '01-01-2017' and '30-01-2017' 
    AND ( Brand = 'Nike' or Brand = 'Jhonson' OR Brand = 'Polo')
```

It can be right with your result.